# How to preserve "visited" links on specific sites?

Tags: browser, history

I use both Chrome and Firefox.

Objectives:

- To preserve visited links for an online course, and maybe a few other sites
- To be able to delete cookies regularly.

For other sites, I don't care if visited links are persistent or not for a reasonable time (weeks). Obviously, if links are persistent forever, then eventually every link on a site would be red.

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean with 'preserve'? In Firefox you can save the history, and export as json file, then with a simple text editor you can edit it.   To clean the browser for cookies, there are tools into the browser and also as extensions.

Comment: Here's what I mean by "preserved". If I open a page, and some links are blue and some are red, then the red links have been "preserved". So IMHO I can gurarantee that the blue links were never visited.  But if all the links are blue, there's no way of knowing whether some links have been "visited" but then "lost". I'm not techie enough to know how links become lost, but I think clearing cookies is one way.

Comment: BTW:  I delayed for 2 hours to answer AndrewQ  and @OpalApps. That's because I was waiting for email notification, as in StackOverflow. Is there no notification on SuperUser?

Answer (score -1):

Use social bookmarking services like [Delicious](https://del.icio.us/), for example. It allows private as well as public book mark collections, tags and search through the public collections of other users that bookmarked same as you did (helps while researching on particular subject)

Comment: I don't think I'm interested in bookmarks. What I'm looking for is as follows. If one of my links in my online course has been visited, it will be red. I want it to remain red for the duration of the course. Eventually, I want every link in my course to be red. If any of those links turn blue, then I'll have to do a lot of trial-and-error to determine which links I've already visited. BTW: the Delicious site is down, and will be restored "Monday, July 24."